# Qt doesn't display child widget

Tags: c++, qt

How can i access ui files of children of a class. Lets say MainWindow class has twoa child dialog. I want to access LINEEDIT of dialog so that i can take text from there. Similarly how can i access ui files of parent inside child class in QT. Note: I havn't inherited any thing from Parent class. 
I have writen the following code, in order to display a dialog but it won't show!

```
void MainWindow::displaydialog()
{
    ItemDialog dialog= new ItemDialog(this);

    dialog->show(); // it is not displaying the dialog
}
```

and how can i access the ui widgets like check whether ListWidget item has been selected or not.

Here is the code of itemdialog,

```
#include "itemdialog.h"
#include "ui_itemdialog.h"
#include "mainwindow.h"

ItemDialog::ItemDialog(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::ItemDialog)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    setWindowTitle("Status Dialog");
setFixedSize(QWidget::sizeHint());
}

ItemDialog::~ItemDialog()
{
delete ui;
}

 void ItemDialog::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    MainWindow obj;
    obj.okbuttonclicked(ui->lineEdit->text());
}
```

Comment: 1. is the `displaydialog` function called at all? 2. Is `Mydialog`'s ctor implemented correctly? and 3. and most importantly: Do not directly access UI of another dialog. Instead, write an accessor member function (getter and/or setter) in the `Mydialog` class. The dialog's UI should only be handled internally.

Answer (score 0):

Please review an example such as this: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/designer-using-a-ui-file.html

It explains how to use the ui files that you generate from Qt Designer. You shouldn't really think of them as "ui files" in the sense of accessing them on the widgets in your class. The idea is that you include them, and then use their `setupUi()` function to apply them to your given class. At that point, everything you created in qt designer, and that is in that ui file, is now a member of your class. They can be accessed via the naming you used in qt designer.

As for why your dialog isn't showing...I don't know  because you only included 3 lines of code as an example. Theoretically it should show if `Mydialog` was properly set up. You could just try changing it to a `QDialog` to make sure you didn't do anything wrong with your custom class.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you want that dialog for. Either it's a modal dialog - some kind of a information display or retrival that blocks the function of your program until user reacts, *or* it's somekind of toolbox or similar, in which case you probably should not use `QDialog`.

If a modal dialog with a line edits and/or additional features is what you want, you should read up on [QDialog](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdialog.html) in the doc. See the `exec()` function. Basic usage would go like this:

```
void MainWindow::displaydialog()
{
  ItemDialog *dialog = new ItemDialog();

  if (dialog->exec() == someApropriateReturnStatus)
  {
    QString somevalue = dialog->someValue();
    int dialog->someOtherValue();
    //do something with the value
  }

  delete dialog;
}
```

The point is that the `ItemDialog` class handles the UI internally and implements the getter functions accordingly, you **should not** (in most typical cases) access it's UI from outside.

If a simple line edit is all you want, you'd be better off using one of the standard dialogs already implemented in Qt, have a look at the [Standard Dialogs Example](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/dialogs-standarddialogs.html)